# Prove or disprove $O(n)^{(O(\log_2 n))} = O(2^n)$

Tags: logarithms, computational-complexity

Prove or disprove $O(n)^{O(\log_2 n)} = O(2^n)$

My naive proof as follows :

There exist a positive $c$ and $n_0$ such that

$$0\leq f(n) \leq cn^{\log_2 n} = c\cdot 2^{(\log_2 n)^2} \leq c\cdot 2^n\space \space \forall n\geq n_0$$

And now, I don't know how to finish the proof properly.

Thank you all sincerely.

Comment: Hint: If the exponent is $2\log_2 n$, what would happen?

Comment: What is $\log_2^n$? What are $x$ and $f(x)$?

Comment: @Trebor Can you give me more hint about that. Cannot figure out a formal way to prove the statement based on that

Comment: What's the statement? You should first figure out whether you need to prove or disprove.